# Dynamic image slider solution

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slider</title>
    <!-- required css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/blog/public/css/jquery.bxslider.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .sliderContainer {
            width: 320px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="float:right;">
    <table style="border:3px solid #00008B;background-color:#90EE90;">
        <h2>1st Advertisement</h2>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a id="adv" href="http://www.w3.org"><img name="noslide" id="noslide" alt="my images" height="240"
                                                          width="320"
                                                          src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-M5lNkr0H3Bk/VJfppu-wPxI/AAAAAAAARhs/FSZY0iVdCF4/s1600/Hand%2BPainting%2Bhd%2Bimagess%2B(3).jpg"/></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font:small-caps bold 15px georgia; color:blue;">
                <div id="fixeddiv">1st Advertisement</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    {{$count=count($slides)}}

    <table style="border:3px solid #00008B;background-color:#90EE90;">
        <h2>2nd Advertisement</h2>
        <div class="sliderContainer">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                @foreach($slides as $key=>$val)
                        <li><a>{{$val->id}}</a><a href="{{$val->link}}"><img src="http://localhost/blog/public/images/{{$val->image_name}}"/></a></li>

                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>


<!-- required js -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            // see documentation for more options
            'auto': true
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

public function index()
    {
        $slides = DB::table('sliders')->get();
        return view('home')->with('slides',$slides);
    }
```

There are four images saved in my db. This is showing the images in a slider, but I want to make it dynamic. I will tell that image 1 will be shown 4 times and image 2 will be 2 times both randomly not serially. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="slide">Slide 1</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
</ul>
```

Then you could try the following:

```
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        'auto': true,
        onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
          // updated newIndex here with your logic

        }
  });
```